# Getting the coordinates of a point that was clicked on renderView

Tags: paraview

I load a DICOM directory in Paraview that renders a 3d head. I want to detect some points in the view. I tried finding the points with the threshold filter but I don't have success in all cases. My next idea is letting the user select the specifics points.

Is there a way to get the coordinates of the points the user clicks on windows view?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the selected points data in a spreadsheet view. As selection is linked between views, the 3d view selection is available in the spreadsheet. Then you can use the `Show only selected elements` button in the spreadsheet to filter data.

*Additional infos*

`Labels` can be added from `Selection Display Inspector`, to automatically display values on selected points in 3d view, but coordinates are not available ... (see this feature request : https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/14422)